# Is it possible to override a component in share.js in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco-share

I want to change the default width of the panel resizer for alfresco share  and I noticed this is set in the share.js dropping the whole file into my extension path just to change the values seems a bit too extreme.

Comment: Well unfortunately that is the only way to go AFAIK. which alfresco version you are using? you want to know if it possible though some configuration?

Comment: Yes. I am using 4.2.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking about in IRC it would seem that this is not possible.